# Cannot reach DNS server on vm (guest) through Sophos XG 310

Tags: firewall, vmware-esxi, internal-dns

I have a vm running Windows Server 2k19 hosted on ESXi that basically acts as a DC for authentication (AD).
The host is connected to a pSwitch (Dell s4128f-on) that is in turn connected to my Sophos XG. The issue is, i can add computers to the domain if i connect straight to the switch, however I cannot through the FW.

One thing to note is, through the FW, when attempting to add a PC to the domain, DNS successfully queries the SRV and does identify the domain controller (1), however is not able to connect to it. That is where i'm stuck.

Do note that I've turned the local VMs firewall off allowing any traffic into the vm.

If someone could shed some ideas on where i possibly went wrong.

My vm's IP is 10.0.0.5/22 . GW is my host's IP (10.0.0.10) and the DNS Server is the vm's IP. I have a different GW on the esxi host itself. Not sure if that would be conflicting.

---

@Turdie - I'll have to check that. Might be something to do with NAT rules too.

@joeqwerty - Thanks for your 1st point. And regarding your second point, I don't have a router on hand to do internal routing. I can use the SW but i wish to keep that on the DC side which is with a NAS. I'm also thinking of probably getting an actual router to do internal routing, because I might be overloading my Sophos XG with traffic ontop of its task as the paramount GW in/out of my network.

Comment: Do you have have port 53 open from the VMs network to the DNS server(udp and tcp). Any logs in the sophos of denied traffic? https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6075/145902

Comment: `1.` Why is your VM using the host ip address as it's gateway? ESXi isn't a router, so it isn't going to route traffic from/to the VM. `2.` Why are you doing this through the firewall instead of on the local network (by connecting everything directly to the switch?